# how to install netcat on genymotion

Tags: genymotion, netcat

I want to install netcat on my genymotion to use wireshark. I tried alot and copied alot of netcat files in to genymotion but what ever i do the nc command will return nc not found.
It's been said than it can be downloaded from the belw link but i dont know what i should do:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/netcat/+/master
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that your `nc` binary is:

- in a directory listed in $PATH?
- marked executable?

Comment: no how should i chek that? it sais that nc command is not valid.I downloaded the file nand extracted it into the genymotion but noting is seems to be installed.there is no executable file maybe.where can i find one?

Answer (score 0):

What you see in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/netcat/+/master is `nc` *source code*, not a ready-to-use binary.

To use it, you need to:

1. Compile the source using the NDK to produce a binary;
2. Send the binary to the device, for example using `adb push path/to/your/nc /system/bin`;

When this is done you should be able to open a shell inside your device with `adb shell` and use nc.

Comment: thanks for your help.Do you know any proper links for doing that?i havent done such a thing till now.

Comment: You would need to be familiar with building things from the AOSP. There is a lot of information here: https://source.android.com/setup/ but that is kind of overwhelming. What are you trying to do? If you want to look at network traffic happening in the device you should be able to do so using Wireshark without installing nc in the device: the device and your machine traffic will be mixed, but you can avoid that by configuring the device in bridge mode. I can give you more instructions if this is what you are trying to do.